# Javascript load image source either jpg or png

Tags: javascript, html

hi i am using javascript to load an image by name either png or jpg. Please help me.

```
<body>
<img id="imageid" />
.....
<script>
...     
    document.getElementById("imageid").src=imgUrl+".png" or ".jpg"
....
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: and the question is? XD or when would you want it (the image source load) to be happened?

Comment: edited. just wanna do some logic with the script so it can load either png or jpg

Comment: most commonly an image-extensions is within an URL, so you dont even need that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try each one using this script

```
var tester=new Image();
tester.onload=function() { // when .png ok
  document.getElementById("imageid").src = imgUrl + '.png';
};
tester.onerror=function() { // when .png failed
  document.getElementById("imageid").src = imgUrl + '.jpg';      
};
tester.src=imgUrl + '.png'; // execute the test
```